# The purpose of functors

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, functor

I am trying to understand functors and do understand the concept but not the purpose of it?

Consider following example:

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3)
val list2 = Functor[List].map(list1)(_ * 2)
```

What is the benefit over:

```
list1.map(x => x * 2)
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose is not necessarily `Functor[List].map(list1)(_ * 2)` but rather:

```
def timesTwo[F[_]: Functor](f: F[Int]) = 
  Functor[F].map(f)(_ * 2)
```

The ability to abstract over everything that can be mapped.

Answer (score 4):

A functor is a type constructor `F[_]` together with a function

```
def fmap[A,B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B]
```

(this is written differently than, e.g., in `cats`, but it achieves the same and is interchangeable)

So what does this mean?
A type constructor is basically a mapping between types You give it a type `A`, and it gives you a result type `F[A]`.

The fact that you have the function `fmap` means the following: You can go from `F[A]` to `F[B]` every time you were able to go from `A` to `B`.

### Laws

Every functor has to obey these identites

1. `fmap(identity[A]) == identity[F[A]]`
2. `fmap(a compose b) == fmap(a) compose fmap (b)`

The functor laws ensure that both the type-level function (the type constructor) and the value level functions (`A => B` and `F[A] => F[B]`) work together well.

### What is the benefit

The benefit is **not** that you can write some function with a different syntax. Indeed in your example `Functor[List].map(list1)(_ * 2)` is more awkward to write than simply `list1.map(_ * 2)`.

The benefit is that you can write functions that work for any functor.

Here is an example

```
import cats.Functor

def foo[A,B,F[_]: Functor](fb: F[B], ab: A => B)(eab: Either[F[A],F[B]]): F[B] = 
    eab.fold(fa => Functor[F].map(fa)(ab),identity)
```

Answer (score 1):

A functor is a type class that abstracts all types of similar map operations that can be made. In doing so, we can operate these types of instances in a uniform way.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful to look at the type signature of functor's map function

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Functor a -> Functor b
```

This gives us a way to put a value in a container (Functor) and operate on that value using an ordinary function (with map), all without having to take the value out of the container.

A Functor can then be considered like a higher-order type; ie, it's a value that contains another value, but has a uniform interface for interacting with it – this interface gives functors a unique form of expression that makes them particularly suitable for certain problems